# Error: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070520)

Tags: iis, migration, windows-server-2019, microsoft, webdeploy

As part of my job, I need to migrate an IIS server but I'm currently running into a problem.

I have a source server where there are two sites/apps and my destination server which is "blank" for the moment.
The two servers don't have the same hostname or IP address but are on the same domain.
On the source server there's an A security certificate and on the destination server a B security certificate.

I used the Microsoft Web Deploy utility, and the installed roles and dependencies are identical on both servers.
From my source server, I export a server package containing the IIS configuration. I move the exported
file to the destination server.

However, as soon as I want to import the file on the destination server, I get the error message :
**Error: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070520)**

I've tried several times and still have the same problem. I've searched the net but nothing very conclusive.

So if anyone has any ideas, any leads, I'd love to hear from you.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It is highly recommended that you sync the servers, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/synchronize-iis#part-1---view-your-sites-dependencies instead of export/import, because that reports issues more verbally.